# How to use ruby inside html tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap progress bar, and i need to dinamically change the progress value, and to do that i must use a ruby variable inside the html tag code, some thing like this:

This is the sample code:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    70%
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what i would like to do:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow=<%= @progress %>
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<%= @progress %>">
    <%= @progress %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try  `style="width: #{@progress} >`

Comment: You need to give some more information about what is happening here.  For example, where is @progress set?  Is this view code in a partial which is being refreshed at regular intervals?  If so what is the trigger to refresh it?

Comment: What is the value of @progress?  Is it `70` or is it `"70%"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your html needs to be rewritten as follows: you're missing some quotes and percentage symbols.  I'm assuming that the value of `@progress` is a number, eg `70`, and i've therefore just replaced every instance of `70` in your desired html with `<%= @progress %>` in the template code.

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%= @progress %>"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<%= @progress %>%">
    <%= @progress %>%
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an equal sign to render it:

```
"width:<%= @progress %>"
```

Comment: Your aria-valuenow is missing some quotes. Maybe this could produce an error. Is there any message in the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= @progress %> is "=" missing 
or use "width:<%= @progress %>px"
```

Comment: width:#{@progress} will return width:200px like that? or only width:200

Comment: @progress return integer value?

Comment: it gives me mismatched property value erro on #{@progress}

Comment: What is "width:<%= @progress %>"  returns?

Comment: px or % is not added in the end of width please add

Comment: "width:<%= @progress %>px"

Comment: it was missing the "%" after the value :((((

Comment: Yes, please add % after the tag. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change these,

```
"aria-valuenow = <%= @progress%>" and
    style="width : #{@progress}"
```